# Music identification site

Tags: discussion, composition

Is there a stack overflow site which allows a user to enter the music they hear in their head as some representation (a musical staff, voice/sound recording,  or even mario music style interface) and then people tell you what the name of that music is (even if the representation corresponds to no music whatsoever and they just call you a dumbass)?

Example:
  I hear dun dun dun duuuuuun.  G-G-G-Eb.  This is Beethoven's 5th symphony wandering around in my head but I don't know the name.  Maybe i'm hearing a transpose of it because I haven't heard it for a while.  I go to this site and somehow input this so others can play it back and tell me it's Beethoven's 5th.  Is there any interest in this kind of technology?

Comment: I'm afraid that there isn't a StackOverflow site with what you're looking for. However, there are services that will identify music based on your humming or singing into a microphone. I suggest trying [SoundHound](http://www.soundhound.com/soundhound) or [looking for other music identification services yourself](https://www.google.com/search?q=music%20identifier).

Comment: http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/ already has a few questions a bit like this, where people have played or sung a melody and asked people to identify the song - though you may still be downvoted if your rendition doesn't seem likely to result in an identification. It's also not a very high-traffic site though so you might not have much luck with anything obscure - and there's no built-in interface, so you'd have to handle the recording yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not part of the SE family of websites, you could try musipedia.org. I've managed to find the names of quite a few pieces/songs using the site.

Answer (score 1):

This again is not a StackExchange site, but IMSLP's [search by melody](http://imslp.org/wiki/IMSLP:Search_by_Melody) feature is sometimes helpful. However, I find that it's often too broad; your search of G--G--G--Ef, for instance, will yield far too many results to be useful.

With that said, the search is of course also limited to the scores on their site.